# View Index is always being rebuilt

Tags: lotus-notes

As of late, I have encountered a problem with my view index being rebuilt all the time and users are having massive issues with this particular view.

I figured it was due to `@Date` in my selection formula aswell as one of my column formulas. This way the selection formula would be different every second that passes.
So I figured, since I dont need hours/minutes/seconds in my formulas, I would use `@Today`. This worked out well for 2-3 days and after that the same problem occured again.

So since the problem is back again, I'm not quite sure if that even causes the problem. When this particular view is open, I have issues in every tab that's open in notes, not only this specific database.

Is this a common/known issue? What can I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a common issue that has been well known since the very early days of Notes more than 20 years ago.

@Date is not a problem on its own.  @Now and @Today are both problems.

Using @TextToTime("Today") was a popular workaround that was discovered early on. This hid the problem from the indexer so the server failed to realize that the view was out of date. It doesn't solve the underlying problem, though, which is that the view is trying to do something that views simply aren't designed to do. Views are intended to be static, requiring update only when documents change. Introducing time into a selection or column formula makes them dynamic, which kills that presumption and is a major source of performance problems. Using this workaround requires that the view be fully rebuilt every night. You can do that by setting the [view index options to "Manual"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27002624), and setting up a [program document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21088932) to run an [updall command with the -T option](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.0.1/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_UPDALL_OPTIONS_3277_STEPS.html) for the specific database and view once per night. Note that if your users are spread out across timezones, you'll have to pick one specific time as your standard, and if you have servers spread out across timezones you're going to have a lot of fun figuring out how to make them all show the same documents in the view at all times - but that's common to pretty much all approaches to the problem.

See this [IBM Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27003557s) for a description of several other options that people have used over the years, with their pros and cons. Also see this [article by Andre Guirard](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/05022009100728pmagu5mb.htm), which covers date/time issues in great detail.

I would add that the agent-and-folder solution that they describe in the Technote was generally my preferred approach, but it does have an additional disadvantage that they don't mention: it can eventually lead to an obscure situation where the server throws an error "Folder is larger than supported". This error actually has nothing to do with the size of the folder in documents; it refers to fragmentation of internal structures that occurs as large numbers of documents are moved in and out of the folder over time. It could only be fixed by deleting and re-creating the folder, which you can do in your agent code. I believe this problem may be fixed in more recent versions of Domino, but it caused me a lot of grief back in the Notes 6 and 7 timeframes.